# Using inline and constexpr in C++

Tags: c++, constants, inline, constexpr

I am working on a robot program for FRC robotics and was curious about if inline or constexpr or both are appropriate for declaring constants.

```
inline constexpr double PI = wpi::math::pi 
inline constexpr double TWO_PI = 2.0 * wpi::math::pi;
inline constexpr units::radian_t PI_RAD = units::radian_t(PI);
inline constexpr units::radian_t TWO_PI_RAD = units::radian_t(TWO_PI);
```

Comment: `constexpr` implies `inline` I believe.

Comment: @0x5453 That is only true for functions and static data members, not for namespace-level variables. For namespace-level variables, `constexpr` implies internal linkage.

Comment: OP: It would be better if you asked a concrete question, otherwise this is mostly a matter of opinion. In my opinion, I would use just `constexpr`, not `inline`. There is usually no need for basic mathematical constants to have external linkage.

Answer (score 2):

Omit `inline` for variables declared in **source** files; it merely invites name collisions.  C++17 added support for inline variables for **header** files: by all means use it there to avoid stupid things like this:

```
#ifndef HEADER_HH
#define HEADER_HH
#include<algorithm>
/* inline */ constexpr int bound=30;
inline int clip(int x) {return std::min(x,bound);}
#endif
```

Any program that `#include`s this header in two different source files is ill-formed, no diagnostic required(!), because `std::min` takes its arguments by reference and thus odr-uses the internal-linkage `bound` which is a **different** variable in every translation unit, denying a single definition for `clip`.

In C++20, though, you can use `export constexpr` (or, for module-private variables, `extern constexpr`) in a **module** interface unit with no need for `inline`.

All this applies for normal `const` (as you must use if the initializer is not a constant expression), with the added bonus that `inline` lets you define a non-`constexpr` `static` class member inside the class (which is useful even in a source file; put the *class* in an anonymous namespace to prevent collisions in that case).